# Connecting MQTT server with OpenHab

Tags: home-automation, openhab

As a sample test, I just want to ON/OFF a bulb using OpenHab via wifi. So I connect the hivemq server and openhab as follows in the openhab configuration.

```
mqtt:broker.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
mqtt:broker.clientId=openhab
```

So when starting openhab I can see following in the console.

```
2016-09-01 19:18:11.692 [INFO ] [.io.transport.mqtt.MqttService] - MQTT Service initialization completed.
2016-09-01 19:18:11.695 [INFO ] [o.i.t.m.i.MqttBrokerConnection] - Starting MQTT broker connection 'broker'
2016-09-01 19:18:13.092 [INFO ] [penhab.io.rest.RESTApplication] - Started REST API at /rest
```

So it seems openhab and hivemq connected successfully. Then I created following file on openhab distribution.

home.sitemap

```
sitemap home label="My House"
{
    Frame label="ESP Module"{
        Group item=FF_Bed label="Front Porch"
    }
}
```

home.items

```
Group All
Group gGF       (All)
Group gFF       (All)

Group GF_Living     "Living Room"   <video>     (gGF)
Group FF_Bed        "Bedroom"       <bedroom>   (gFF)

Dimmer Light_GF_Living_Table        "Table"         (GF_Living, Lights)     {mqtt="<[mybroker:/myHome/Table:command:ON]"}
Switch Light_FF_Bed_Ceiling         "Ceiling"       (FF_Bed, Lights)        {mqtt="<[mybroker:/myHome/doorbell:command:ON]"}

/* Locations */
Location HomeLocation  MyHome
```

esp-pic.map

```
0=Still
1=Motion
```

I can see above specified items on my openhab site. But when I click on the light there are no updates from the MQTT server. But I can see following on OpenHab console.

```
2016-09-02 12:00:35.484 [INFO ] [runtime.busevents             ] - Light_FF_Bed_Ceiling received command ON
```

So why it doesn't publish this change to HiveMQ topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have inbound or outbound mqtt messages in openHAB.

Your current configuration in home.items is inbound because of the "<"-sign.
If you want to a click on the switch to cause a mqtt-message to be published to the broker, you have to change it to the ">"-sign.

For reference have look on this page: https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/MQTT-Binding and search for inbound or outbound messages

Comment: Ok I changed it to ">" but still I couldn't find topics on MQTT.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. With the proposed change and having org.openhab.binding.mqtt-1.8.3.jar on addon (earlier I only had org.openhab.action.mqtt-1.8.3.jar) this is working fine.